# Kannel configuration for Android

Tags: android, kannel

I want to connect Android Phone with my PC and send SMS through my PC. **Is it possible?**
I want to configure SMS gateway such as Kannel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you may send SMS from Android and also accept incoming SMS from within your App.

Just search for "send SMS" and/or "accept incoming SMS" with Android.

Comment: I never intended to reject any answer, actually I don't know before how to accept answers.......................Thank you dear

Answer (score 2):

If you configure Kannel, you can send sms using your PC through your Android phone as modem. Normal sms charges will be charged by your mobile operator.